Problem with displaying JPG images in spring application through Vaadins UI
I'm developing a spring application. I'm using Vaadin for building user interface.
I have class like this which should be responsible for displaying images.
@SpringComponent
@Scope("prototype")
@AnonymousAllowed
@Route(value="galery", layout=MainLayout.class)
@PageTitle("Photogalery")
public class GaleryView extends VerticalLayout{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Image pngImage = new Image("images/user.png","static image png ");
    private Image jpegImage = new Image("images/IMG_1797.JPG","static image jpg");  
    private Image airplane = new Image("images/airplane.png","");
    private Image appleTouch = new Image("images/apple-touch-icon.png","");

    public GaleryView() {
        add(pngImage);
        add(jpegImage);
        add(airplane);
        add(appleTouch);
    }

PNG images are displayed as expected, but problem is with JPG images, which are not displayed, just hepler text is displayed. Images are stored inside src/main/resources/META-INF/resouces/images folder. That is the way, which is recommended by Vaadin, for displaying images in Spring application. But I tried also other ways, none was worked. I'm using Tomcat as webserver, I'm not sure whether it's needed to configure Tomcat somehow, but I cannot google much about that.
Please, Is here someone who has experience with problem like this?
I tried also different file path for images.
I also tried rename images, for example from IMG_1797.JPG to IMG_1797.JPEG and vice versa(I don't know where exactly is the difference), but nothing worked.

You are using Spring, you should be use Resource class and classpath: prefix to help you to load the content.

You are loading the images correctly according to the Vaadin docs.
Do you have a security config that is not permitting these types of files? If so, you'll want to make sure *.jpg or *.jpeg s added. It might look like this:
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/images/*.png"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/images/*.jpg"),
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/images/*.svg")
                ).permitAll());

        // ...
    }
}


Yes, the problem was in my SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity. I had only *.png but not *.jpg, but I didn't realise it until I read your answer. So you fixed my issue, thank you very much.
